# How to split HTML P tag content by line without line break

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

When the content exceeds the tag width, the content will auto break into new line.
How to split the tag content by line?

Expect Result: each line content
Same question but not solved: [Read text within an HTML <p> tag line by line in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854975/read-text-within-an-html-p-tag-line-by-line-in-javascript)

Comment: Try looking at answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps) post

Comment: I think you can use regex for this

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve?  You're trying to determine how the rendering is working out?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out whether I can compute the container width, then divide the font size to get the each line word number, split according to the word number.

Comment: @Brad: I'm facing a problem that split content in table element.when content height exceeds table height, I need to split content into a new table

Comment: @ekirio I don't follow exactly what it is you're trying to do, but it sounds fishy.  Why would you need to split data into a new table?  Table elements follow semantics... can you elaborate?

Comment: @Brad yes. We have a HTML element which contains table element,  we transfer the html content to the backend and convert it into pdf file. But when the table height exceeds paper height,  the page bottom will lose table bottom border. And my idea is split the table into two new table and put content into it. This needs to calculate the height and split each line of content.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes much much more sense.  There is a way in CSS to adjust your table rows in the way that they roll to the next page... I don't remember the specifics as I haven't messed with print CSS in probably a decade, but I'd recommend going that route rather than modifying the elements on the page, if at all possible.

Answer (score -1):

Just a javascript alternative
`document.getElementById('P TAG').innerHTML+="\n your text"`

Comment: Method innerText or textContent isn't contain "\n", it cant use "\n" to split.